# Unable to reproduce simple figure from textbook (possible numerical instability)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am trying to reproduce figure 5.6 (attached) from the textbook "Modeling Infectious Diseases in Humans and Animals ([official code repo](http://www.modelinginfectiousdiseases.org/))" (Keeling 2008) to verify whether my implementation of a seasonally forced SEIR (epidemiological model) is correct. An official program from the textbook that implements seasonal forcing indicates that large values of Beta 1 can lead to numerical errors, but if the figure has Beta 1 values that did not lead to numerical errors, then in principle this should not be the cause of the problem. My implementation correctly produces the graphs in row 0, column 0 and row 1, column 0 of figure 5.6 but there is no output in my figure for the remaining cells due to the numerical solution for the fraction of infected (see code at bottom) producing 0 (and the ln(0) --> -inf).

I do receive the following warnings:

> ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call

> C:\Users\jared\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_24972\2802449019.py:68:
> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log   infected =
> np.log(odeint(

> C:\Users\jared\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_24972\2802449019.py:68:
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log   infected =
> np.log(odeint(

Here is the textbook figure:

[image]

My figure within the same time range (990 - 1000 years). Natural log taken of fraction infected:

[image]

My figure but with a shorter time range (0 - 100 years). Natural log taken of fraction infected. The numerical solution for the infected population seems to fail between the 5 and 20 year mark for most of the seasonal parameters (Beta 1 and R0):

[image]

My figure with a shorter time range as above, but with **no** natural log taken of fraction infected.

[image]

Code to reproduce my figure:

```py
# Code to minimally reproduce figure
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def seir(y, t, mu, sigma, gamma, omega, beta_zero, beta_one):
    """System of diff eqs for epidemiological model.

    SEIR stands for susceptibles, exposed, infectious, and
    recovered populations. 

    References:
        [SEIR Python Program from Textbook](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masfz/ModelingInfectiousDiseases/Chapter2/Program_2.6/Program_2_6.py)
        [Seasonally Forced SIR Program from Textbook](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masfz/ModelingInfectiousDiseases/Chapter5/Program_5.1/Program_5_1.py)
    """
    s, e, i = y
    beta = beta_zero * (1 + beta_one * np.cos(omega * t))
    sdot = mu - (beta*i + mu)*s
    edot = beta*s*i - (mu  + sigma)*e
    idot = sigma*e - (mu + gamma)*i
    return sdot, edot, idot

def solve_beta_zero(basic_reproductive_rate, gamma):
    """Defined in the last paragraph of pg. 159 of textbook Keeling 2008."""
    return gamma * basic_reproductive_rate

# Model parameters (see Figure 5.6 description)
mu = 0.02 / 365
sigma = 1/8
gamma = 1/5
omega = 2 * np.pi / 365  # frequency of oscillations per year

# Seasonal forcing parameters
r0s = [17, 10, 3]
b1s = [0.02, 0.1, 0.225]

# Permutes params to get tuples matching row i column j params in figure
# e.g., [(0.02, 17), (0.02, 10) ... ]
seasonal_params = [p for p in itertools.product(*(b1s, r0s))]

# Initial Conditions: I assume these are proportions of some total population
s0 = 6e-2
e0 = i0 = 1e-3
initial_conditions = [s0, e0, i0]

# Timesteps
nyears = 1000
days_per_year = 365
ndays = nyears * days_per_year
timesteps = np.arange(1, ndays+1, 1)

# Range to slice data to reproduce my figures
# NOTE: CHange the min slice or max slice for different ranges
min_slice = 990  # or 0
max_slice = 1000 # or 100
sliced = slice(min_slice * days_per_year, max_slice * days_per_year)
x_ticks = timesteps[sliced]/days_per_year

# Define figure
nrows = 3
ncols = 3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex=True, figsize=(15, 8))

# Iterate through parameters and recreate figure
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):

        # Get seasonal parameters for this subplot
        beta_one = seasonal_params[i * nrows + j][0]
        basic_reproductive_rate = seasonal_params[i * nrows + j][1]

        # Compute beta zero given the reproductive rate
        beta_zero = solve_beta_zero(
            basic_reproductive_rate=basic_reproductive_rate, 
            gamma=gamma)

        # Numerically solve the model, extract only the infected solutions,
        # slice those solutions to the desired time range, and then natural 
        # log scale them
        solutions = odeint(
            seir, 
            initial_conditions, 
            timesteps, 
            args=(mu, sigma, gamma, omega, beta_zero, beta_one))

        infected_solutions = solutions[:, 2]

        log_infected = np.log(infected_solutions[sliced])

        # NOTE: To inspect results without natural log, uncomment the
        # below line
        # log_infected = infected_solutions[sliced]

        # DEBUG: For shape and parameter printing
        # print(
        #     infected_solutions.shape, 'R0=', basic_reproductive_rate, 'B1=', beta_one)

        # Plot results
        ax[i,j].plot(x_ticks, log_infected)
        
        # label subplot
        ax[i,j].title.set_text(rf'$(R_0=${basic_reproductive_rate}, $\beta_{1}=${beta_one})')

fig.supylabel('NaturalLog(Fraction Infected)')
fig.supxlabel('Time (years)')
```

Disclaimer:

My short term solution is to simply change the list of seasonal parameters to values that will produce data for that range, and this adequately illustrates the effects of seasonal forcing. The point is to reproduce the figure, though, and if the author was able to do it, others should be able to as well.

Comment: Did the program even finish? It could be that for some reason the internal step size is so small that the computation time becomes prohibitive. Perhaps try to reduce the displayed time range to 90..100 years? Only compute and display 60 points per year, not the full 365? Actually more than 500 (200?) points per plot will not make a visible difference. Split the integration into 2, once for the silent segment with minimal output and then for the displayed segment?

Comment: Do you get any warnings or error messages?  If so, include the *complete* message in the question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I added the error messages that I get. They are divide by 0 errors that occur in when taking the natural log of 0.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The program does finish. I tried changing the displayed time range and updated my question to reflect these changes. The same issues still occur. I think the new figures also show that the "silent" segment does have calculations occurring, but for some reason the numerical solution goes to 0 (see the last figure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first (and possibly main) problem is one of scale. This diagnosis is also conform with the observations in your later experiments. The system is such that if it is started with positive values, it should stay within positive values. That negative values are reached is only possible if the step errors of the numerical method are too large.

As you can see in the original graphs, the range of values goes from `exp(-7) ~= 9e-4` to `exp(-12) ~= 6e-6`. The value of the absolute tolerance should force at least 3 digits to be exact, so `atol = 1e-10` or smaller. The relative tolerance should be adapted similarly. Viewing all components together shows that the first component has values around `exp(-2.5) ~= 5e-2`, so per-component tolerances should provide better results. The corresponding call is

```
        solutions = odeint(
            seir, 
            initial_conditions, 
            timesteps, 
            args=(mu, sigma, gamma, omega, beta_zero, beta_one),
            atol = [1e-9,1e-13,1e-13], rtol=1e-11)
```

With these parameters I get the plots below

[image]

The first row and first column are as in the cited graphic, the others look different.

---

As a test and a general method to integrate in the range of small positive solutions, reformulate for the integration of the logarithms of the components. This can be done with a simple wrapper

```
def seir_log(log_y,t,*args):
    y = np.exp(log_y)
    dy = np.array(seir(y,t,*args))
    return dy/y  # = d(log(y))
```

Now the expected values have scale 1 to 10, so that the tolerances are no longer so critical, default tolerances should be sufficient, but it is better to work with documented tolerances.

```
        log_solution = odeint(
            seir_log,
            np.log(initial_conditions), 
            timesteps, 
            args=(mu, sigma, gamma, omega, beta_zero, beta_one), 
            atol = 1e-8, rtol=1e-9)

        log_infected = log_solution[sliced,2]
```

The bottom-left plot is still sensible to `atol`, with `1e-7` one gets a more wavy picture. Bounding the step size with `hmax=5` also stabilizes that. With the code as above the plots are

[image]

The center plot is still different than the reference. It might be that there are different stable cycles.

Comment: So I had to do a bit of reading on error tolerance in numerical integration since that's completely new to me, so I apologize if these are unclear questions. I don't quite understand why you choose `reltol=[1e-9, 1e-13, 1e-13]` and `atol=1e-11`. Why those numbers? I also don't understand why you implemented the `seir_log` function. I see that you first scale the conditions for the state variables at a time step t with the line `y = np.exp(y)`, then the vector of solutions to the SEIR diffeqs is computed with the line `dy = ...`, but then you rescale those solutions with `dy/y`. Why?

Comment: If you have any solid book recommendations or sites that you think might help clarify your choices as it relates to error tolerance and numerical integration, I would be very grateful. I briefly skimmed several sites, but the concepts are still unclear to me.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "different stable cycles"?

Comment: You have a periodically forced dynamical system. Obviously the windows we see are quite regular, apparently periodic. In the 3D state space this corresponds to a stable cycle. There may be multiple stable cycles in the same example, just as there may be multiple stable equilibrium points in some planar system. Where you get to from some random initial condition may be sensible to the initial point, and consequently also to the accumulated errors of a numerical integration.

Comment: As to the first comment, these are the parameters that work in giving a stable result. Looser bounds, that is greater values, give errors in the integration, failing to produce a result, give a diverging result etc. The error tolerances and a dynamic estimate of the error are used to produce locally optimal step sizes for the error level and stability. /// In the logarithmic formulation the solver is presented only the logarithms of the state. So in computing the derivatives the state is restored via exponential, and in the end `d(log(y))=dy/y` is used for the logarithmic derivative.

Comment: Why is the `seir_log` func a "general method to integrate in the range of small positive solutions"? Is "reformulat[ing] for the integration of the logarithms of the components" something that is widely used in problems where the solutions are small and positive? If so, do you have some sort of reference for this or other examples where this occurs? Is numerically solving the dynamical system with the logarithms of the state "more stable" if the absolute values of the state values are higher? And why do the "expected values have a scale of 1-10"? What do you mean exactly by "expected values"?

Comment: Using the parametrization `y = exp(u)` makes large scale changes in `y` into relatively small changes in the exponent `u`. This does of course not work where a sign change is expected, but works well in enforcing a positive sign. One could also do a more general substitution `y=v*exp(u)`  with the expectation that the factor `v` has small and slow variations. Replacing one variable by two introduces a degree of freedom that can be used up to set some non-trivial sub-expressions to zero. I'm not aware of any specific book for such tricks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248474/discussion-between-jared-frazier-and-lutz-lehmann).